# Is there any way to navigate inside frames on a webpage using Nightmare JS?

Tags: html, node.js, frame, nightmare

I am having trouble using Nightmare js to access elements within a specific frame on a webpage that gets its elements from a different html file. These are frames, not iframes, so plugins such as iframe-manager do not work.

I also cannot go to the src page of the frame as what I am attempting to do opens another window when clicked on the frames html.

On the original webpage clicking the button on the frame reveals information within another frame on the webpage. It would be easier (and potentially possible, unlike other options) to navigate within frames on the original webpage.

Any guidance would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: check out https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/203 and https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-iframe-manager

Comment: These are frames, not iframes so it doesn't appear that nightmare-iframe-manager will work.



The first link led to the creation of the nightmare-iframe package, which similarly does not appear to work as these are not iframes. That package also no longer works as the Ninghtmare shifted from being based in PhantomJS to Electron

Comment: oops, sorry, I missed read frames as iframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to cut my losses and switch to puppeteerJS

Unlike Nightmare, it supports switching to normal frames via their `contentFrame()` method and `$`

No shade on Nightmare though, its a good API, just lost support for this frankly archaic web design choice